# Outlook new email notification banner - can't figure out how to silence

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, notifications

I appreciate how many alerts I can turn off, but there's one I still can't figure out. I use the Focused folder, which is a great help. But if another email arrives, I get a notification like the one below. It's a grey bar that appears above all of the emails, across the top of the folder I'm working in, and it disappears after I go over to the folder the message came into. It pushes everything down a couple of rows, which also throws me off, if I'm just going through deleting things.

You should be able to turn this off, or at a minimum, be able to configure it. If you're in the "Other" folder, and something comes into "Focused," I could imagine someone wanting to know something is there. But if I'm in Focused, I really don't need you to tell me about a new newsletter I'll read later, (or some new email offer from Southwest, or whoever).

For some who has made the efforts to avoid having their workflow interrupted by removing all other alerts, this is particularly annoying.
Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Focused and Other aren't new inboxes or folders. It's an attempt at organizing Inbox to show important and directed to you emails in Focused view, and more generic and addressed to large amount of people emails in other view.

Here is an official document: [Change how your messages get organized](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/focused-inbox-for-outlook-f445ad7f-02f4-4294-a82e-71d8964e3978)

Comment: Thanks for helping me with the proper language. My Inbox has two "tabs," Focused, and Other. But I'm still looking for a way to not see an alert across the top of my Inbox every time I'm in one tab and an email comes into the other tab. If I'm in Focused, and a new email comes in to Focused, I don't get the alert. But if I'm in Other, and an email comes in to Focused, I get the alert. But how do I turn off this alert? Thanks